# on rotate mobile webview refresh hide menu

Tags: android, webview, web

i have a problem i am create an app web view to get and website on play store.

the problem is that it have a dropdown Menu html5+jquery+css3. when i rotate the smartphone, the web are refreshed.

this my code Android Studio 3.0:

Activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.icarosnet.icarosnetsa.IcarosWeb">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/wv"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main.Java

```
package com.icarosnet.icarosnetsa;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class IcarosWeb extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView wv ;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(wv.canGoBack()){
            wv.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_icaros_web);
        wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setFocusable(true);
        wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        wv.loadUrl("https://icarosnet.com");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState ){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        wv.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        wv.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Xml Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.icarosnet.icarosnetsa">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".IcarosWeb">
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

does not respect the content that was loaded by ajax.

how can i prevent refresh and resize the view; or how can i show it only portrait and block the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
It saves state onPause for WebView.

```
@Override 
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webViewBundle = new Bundle();
    wv.saveState(webViewBundle);
  }
```

Add in OnCreate:

```
if (webViewBundle == null) {
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.setFocusable(true);
wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
wv.loadUrl("https://icarosnet.com");
} else {
wv.restoreState(webViewBundle);
}
```

*Assuming wv would be declared for the class

Answer (score 0):

```
  <activity android:name=".TestActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">  

write this line and show it only portrait
```

Comment: Please update your code-only answer to explain some of the logic of why this works.

Comment: please look at [answer]

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `android:screenOrientation = "potrait"` inside `activity` tag in `manifest` file to make your `Activity` not rotate to `landscape` even when phone is rotated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <activity
                android:name="YourActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: Please make an explanation in order to help better to the question poster instead of just providing a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState )
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        wv.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        wv.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"><intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```